# How to iterate the range of numbers in a list?

Tags: python, loops

So this may sound like a dumb question and maybe I'm overthinking this, but I'm struggling to figure out how to iterate the range of numbers in a list. Say I have a list of numbers [100, 500, 1000]. I don't necessarily want to iterate through this list, but I want to iterate through the values if that makes sense. So I'm guessing I would iterate through the list first, but then I would need to create another loop for the values?

```
   for i in mylist:
        for j in range(0, mylist[i]):
             do something
```

I feel like this may be inefficient but would this be the way to do that?

Comment: remove the second line, and do something with `i`, e.g. `print(i)`

Comment: Also, your code above, where it says "mylist[i]", I think should be just "i", or you can change the "for" statement to "for i in range(len(mylist))"

Comment: if you don't get an acceptable answer, consider including your expected output for a given input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already fetching value from *mylist* in the first for loop. After than in the range you can just put that value directly (ie in second for loop) as shown below.

```
mylist = [100, 500, 1000]

for i in mylist:
    for j in range(0, i):
             print(j)
```

Comment: Thanks sb9 I think this is exactly want, to be more clear, I have a list of steps I'm taking 10, 20, 50, etc. but these won't be taken in the same trial I guess if that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of numbers and you want to add up all the numbers and use that as the number of loops, you can do:

```
for i in range(sum(mylist)):
  #do_something
```